# Синхронизация двух сайтов

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток! Вопрос в следующем: нужно сделать что бы при изменении информации на одном сайте, те же изменения происходили на втором. Объясню поподробней, сейчас на двух сайтах одинаковая инфа, но когда на первом сайте удаляют/изменяют/добавляют данные, на второй сайт отправляется сигнал($_GET/$_POST) об этом и второй сайт запрашивает нужную информацию и обновляет свою БД. Но возникает вопрос коллизии, если к одним и тем же данным обратились одновременно два пользователя, но один изменил эту информацию, а второй удалили(или тоже изменил). Как можно избавиться от коллизии? Кто-нибудь делал подобное, можете дать совет в какую сторону копать. Думал сделать очередь из поступивших запросов и исполнять их по порядку, но пока не получается эту очередь сформировать.

**Обновление**

На одну базу к сожалению нельзя, только получать данные с первого сайта. Для этого есть функционал, но нужно избавиться от коллизии. Думал вместе с "сигналом" получать время изменения данных, но что если пришел сигнал об изменении, началась обработка и запись данных в БД, затем на сервере первого сайта подвели часы и еще раз изменили данные. По сути сигнал пришел позже, а полученное время изменений данных меньше предыдущего, а значит этот запрос не выполниться. Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Нужно сделать чтобы оба сайта смотрели на одну базу. В общем случае решение этой задачи намного проще чем той что вы описали.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Вам правильно подсказывают: синхронизировать базу. Не надо усложнять, наоборот, всегда стремитесь к простому варианту. Вам нужна репликация данных типа мастер-мастер.  
Либо, если конфигурация позволяет, просто прокинуть защищенное соединение и на одном из серверов использовать базу другого сервера.

Comment: Я все это понимаю. Просто на первом сайте часть данных храниться в объектах а не в БД, поэтому есть api, с помощью которого я получаю эти данные и записываю уже в БД на втором сайте. С удовольствием сделал бы проще, но не получается. А на крон вешать отказались, хотят что бы данные изменялись мгновенно.

Comment: Проблема начинается с того, что на первом сервере не решена проблема коллизий. При правильной логике приложения не должно иметь значения откуда поступил запрос на модификацию данных: с этого же сервера или через HTTP-запрос с другого сервера. Реализуйте функционал CRUD для совместно используемых данных на основном сервере и представьте API к нему для доступа со второго сервера.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то используя crud, можно изменять данные но на основном сервере. А у меня два сайта и две бд, только с одинаковыми данными. API которое предоставляет данные есть(soap).